# access to string by included library

Tags: android

I've created my own library. I added it to another project. Inside library I need to get String from strings.xml. I used

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)
```

in library's service but it returned "res/layout/dialog.xml". 
Here's my question - how do I access String inside included library that is in app? (it's .jar that I've put in "libs" folder).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here about [Managing android projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html)

In short all your library resources will be moved to the new project's resources, and in case of conflict (two resources have the same ID) the app resources would be visible.

So try using unique resource IDs for your library project to make sure it is safe to access them from any project.